# Saving UIState of resource-heavy fragment

Tags: android

I do know how to save data between config changes (using onSavedInstanceState and checking the Bundle in onCreate, for example, for not being `null`) and I also do know how to make data persistent (via `SharedPreferences`), but here I need an in-between-solution.

I have a resource-heavy fragment which gets killed (`onDestroyView()` and `onDestroy()` are being called) when I replace it with another resource-heavy fragment. When I return to the former, its state is gone (the Bundle is `null`), making it persistent would save state across "sessions" which contradicts state-saving in other fragments. Is there a way how have "session-scoped" persistence in Android? By "session-scoped" I mean a period longer than the Android life-cycle and shorter than "forever".

Comment: If these fragments are in the same activity, use a shared (activity-scoped) `ViewModel`.

Comment: You can detach your fragment instead of removing it. That way only its view hierarchy will be destroyed (and recreated when re-attaching it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are a bunch of ways of saving the fragment and activity states.

1. If you have several fragments and an activity, and you are simply replacing the fragment view with those fragments then you may use graph level `ViewModel`. Check out navigation architecture component.
2. If you just want to save the state of the fragment, just create ViewModel for fragment view and make its lifecycle as activity lifecycle. So the ViewModel does not get cleared or killed until the host activity for the fragment is destroyed.

You may check out view model here in Android Documentation: [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Here is the good comparison for managing saved states, which options to consider 1) ViewModel, 2)Saved states  or 3) Persistence storage

Depending on the size of data and context you may choose one of the given options. I would fully recommend reading it. Here is the link

[Saving UI States](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states)